# Problem in iterating over an integer list

Tags: python, loops, typeerror

I have this code

```
class Solution:
    def fizzBuzz(self, n: int) -> List[str]:
        l = []
        starting_pos = n-n+1
        ending_pos = n+1
        for i in range(starting_pos, ending_pos):
            l = [i]
            for j in l:
                if j % 5 == 0 and j % 3 == 0:
                    l.insert(j, "FizzBuzz")
                if j % 3 == 0:
                    l.insert(j, "Fizz")
                if j % 5 == 0:
                    l.insert(j, "Buzz")
                else:
                    continue
```

and when I run this, I get this error

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
    if j % 5 == 0 and j % 3 == 0:
Line 9 in fizzBuzz (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().fizzBuzz(param_1)
Line 37 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 48 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

I can't seem to fix this. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: The traceback of the error is incomplete.

Comment: What's Solution.py? Is this running in LeetCode?

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? Do you know what the error message means? Do you know why it's happening? Do you know how to fix it? Please read [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea Why would I ask if I know how to fix it Imao

Comment: @Debarka Hypothetically, maybe you know how to fix it, but not how to write it in Python.

Comment: I saw this error for the first time

Comment: Nothing to do with the error, but why `starting_pos = n-n+1` - surely it's easier just to use `starting_pos = 1`

Comment: You don't need to iterate over `l` at all. You are iterating over the integers from 1 to n+1; all you need to do is append a string or integer (as appropriate for the value of `i`) to `l`.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting strings (`"FizzBuzz"`, etc.) into the list `l`, over which you iterate.

`j` is an int at first but later it becomes a string. The meaning of `%` is completely different for ints and strings. So the expression `j % 5` means the remainder (`j mod 5`) when `j` is an `int`, but later it is interpreted as [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting), which fails with the error you see.

What you probably should be doing instead is work with the value of `i` and drop the inner loop altogether.